# Table selection behaves strangely

Tags: macos, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am very new with SwiftUI (last time I created a macOS app it was still on NIB/XIB and ObjectiveC)

The main view is based on a `Table`. It represents a model mapped via Firestore using Swift Codable.

```swift
class Item: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var description: String
```

I have issues both with single selection and multiple selection -- for two different reasons.

## Single selection

```
struct MainWindowView: View {
    // Table and searchable.
    @State private var searchedQuery: String = ""
    @State var selectedItemID: Item.ID?
...
   Table(selection: $selectedItemID, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
   ....
}
```

`selectedItemID` is `nil` by default. When I select a row I get a selection (if I print `selectedItemID` I get `Optional(xxxxx)`. If I deselect the row, `selectedItemID` is now `Optional(nil)` instead of being `nil`. This messes with my conditions on disabling some UI items as `selectedItemID == nil` is false.

## Multiple selection

I would like to move to multiple selections but here I get a very strange behaviour and a crash.

I change my `selectedItemID` into a `Set<Item>`. But now if I select a row, it gets automatically de-selected and if I select another row I get an exception that the Set has duplicate elements

I am sure I am doing something wrong but I could not find anything on the web. The only similar issue got solved by making the ID not nullable, but that was using CoreData and Firestore `@DocumentID` must be optional.